# Find all paths with smallest weight if there are many relations between two nodes using cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

The thing is I have to find all paths whith the smallest weight and max depth could be 6 (5 vertices could be in the middle). Between two vertices can be more relations with different weight.

For example Path:

`weight(ABEF) = 2+3+1 = 6` or `2+2+1 = 5` if we choose different relations weight between nodes B and E.

And the same for other roads - there can be different weight between the same nodes because of different relations.

The database is huge and calculating all possibilities in depth 6 is looong time :/

How can I check once all relations weight between two nodes and in the same search not check those with largest weight and if there are relations with the same smallest weight, then take them both?

So far I have:

```
START n=node(158371), m=node(183090)
MATCH p=n-[r*..4]-m
WITH p, length(p) as len,r
RETURN  reduce(res=0, x in r: res + x.weight) as totalscore, len
ORDER BY totalscore desc;
```

but the database breaks if I search in depth 6 and find all possibilities. And reduce function acts like collecting strings but I need to count weight. (`2+3+1=6 not 2+3+1=231`)

P.s. If the graphical image is not visible, it's here: http://postimg.org/image/bf9rfdtf7/

Comment: Did you by chance store your weights as string? Usually reduce works just fine with numeric values.

Comment: Did you count how many paths you find with a length of 6 ? Perhaps you should use `p=allShortestPaths(n-[r*..6]-m)`

Comment: In csv file when I uploaded there wasn't specified type, just column called 'weight'. I needed to do like 'weight:int'?

When I count total paths with a lenght of 6 there were more thousands, and I tried allShortestPaths, but sometimes the smallest weight is for largest path.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a typical problem to be solved with the [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Unfortunately, I don't think Cypher syntax exists for that, but an implementation is shipped with Neo4j [if you didn't mind using Java](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html#dijkstra%28org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipExpander,%20java.lang.String%29), or the [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-with-weights-on-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra Agorithm sounds the real problem solver in this case! But I was wondering if I have many criteries then I could filter first by those where I expect less returned results and then find the cheapest path could be much faster.

But is it possible in Cypher to store weight and path in array  were I put only the current cheapest paths, but when there are even cheapest then delete all content in array and put there new cheapest paths and eventually return array?